# BigQuery Repeating Job load does not re-load the schema

Tags: google-bigquery, jobs

I have a daily task where tables are loaded from csv files stored in the Cloud Storage bucket.  Our team does a repeat job load from job history using the console.  One of our users recently is getting a message 'Empty schema specified for the load job. Please specify a schema that describes the data being loaded'. This happens after he clicks repeat job load on a job that has previously been successful. It appears as though the schema or table settings are not loading from the previous job.

When other users try to repeat the same job it works fine.  What has changed for the user that it no longer works? I have had a look at permissions and the user is an Owner.

Comment: I dont think it is related to permission. What is the schema type defined in load job? is it auto select or is it defined? Also, what is the write preference of the job?

Comment: For most tables the previous jobs have had auto select and a couple have defined.  It does not work for either scenario